# How to use CHM HTML Help file with Delphi XE application?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, chm, html-help

Delphi - How to use CHM HTML Help file with Delphi XE application?

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27842 article describes how to use CHM file. 
I did all the steps described there.

Added

```
const
  HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC        = $0000;
  HH_DISPLAY_TOC          = $0001;
  HH_CLOSE_ALL            = $0012;

function HtmlHelp(hwndCaller: HWND;
  pszFile: PChar; uCommand: UINT;
  dwData: DWORD): HWND; stdcall;
  external 'HHCTRL.OCX' name 'HtmlHelpA';
```

and public function HH`

```
function TForm1.HH(Command: Word; Data: Integer;
  var CallHelp: Boolean): Boolean;
begin
  if (Command = 0) and (Data = 0) then
      HtmlHelp(Application.Handle,
        PChar(Application.HelpFile),
        HH_DISPLAY_TOC, 0);

  CallHelp := False;
end;
```

In FormCreate

```
  HelpDir:=ExtractFilePath(Application.EXEName);
  Application.HelpFile:=HelpDir+'Sample.chm';
  Application.OnHelp := HH;
```

On the button1 OnClick event added the following code:

```
HH(0, 0, dummy);
```

After clicking on the button1, cursor becomes an hourglass for a while, and that's all.

What I'm doing wrong ?

And how the CHM help file can be used from DelphiXE application?

Comment: Don't you just add HtmlHelpViewer to your uses clause? And that should be it.

Comment: HTMLHelpViewer is in my uses clause,so it's not the reason.

Comment: If you use that you need nothing else

Comment: Thank You. I've created a help test project. It works there. But it doesn't work in my main project ((, which is a MDI application.

Comment: Clearly you've got something wrong in your project. Can't tell what from here.

Comment: Use HtmlHelpW instead of HtmlHelpA if you are using Unicode (XE already support Unicode).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The article you are working from pre-dates built in support for HTML help. These days you do the following:

- Include `HtmlHelpViewer` in at least one of your uses clauses.
- Set `Application.HelpFile` to the path of your help file.

And that's it. The code in your question should be removed. The built-in help viewer takes care of all those details.

Comment: `Include HtmlHelpViewer` and `Set Application.HelpFile` and like a miracle everything goes by itself. OP has informed you `HTMLHelpViewer is in my uses clause,so it's not the reason.` Also as you can clearly see he uses `Application.HelpFile:=HelpDir+'Sample.chm';` and now? Your answer has as always immediately 2 upvotes. But can not help OP. This is a pity.

Comment: @moskito I don't understand your comment

Comment: Just in case someone still use Delphi 5 (same as me) it should be UseHTMLHelp instead of HtmlHelpViewer.