# How do I attach an OnHelp event handler to the Application object?

Tags: delphi, chm

In Embarcadero Delphi XE7, I use a component which has a help-button.
In the component (which shows a message dialog), I specify a help context number. If the user clicks on the button, the help should show, but I get an error instead:

> Project ... raised exception class $C00000FD with message 'stack overflow at 0x006f089e'.

The command executed when the user clicks on the button is:

```pascal
Application.HelpContext(HelpContextNumber);
```

On [Launch HTML Help as Separate Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336018/), I read that I should attach an `OnHelp` event handler to the Application object.

I saved the Help unit but how do I attach it?

```pascal
Application.OnHelp := ....?
```

Comment: Please add some relevant tags to your question by using the `edit`button. I assume it's Delphi?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534449/how-to-use-chm-html-help-file-with-delphi-xe-application

Comment: I know how to attach a htmlhelp file to my application. On other points in my app the help show coerrect. Only not from this component.That is why I want to try the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336018/launch-html-help-as-separate-process but I don't know how to attach the help file to the application.

Comment: I don't quite understand what your question is. Do you want to know how to create a function that you can assign to `Application.OnHelp`, or do you want to know what that procedure should do?

Answer (score 0):

The [`TApplication.OnHelp`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnHelp) event is declared as a [`THelpEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.THelpEvent):

```pascal
THelpEvent = function(Command: Word; Data: THelpEventData; var CallHelp: Boolean): Boolean of object;
```

So, you would need to declare a method in your Form like this:

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    ...
  private
    function MyOnHelpHandler(Command: Word; Data: THelpEventData; var CallHelp: Boolean): Boolean;
    ...
  end;
```

And then you can assign that handler to the `TApplication.OnHelp` event at runtime, eg:

```pascal
procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnHelp := MyOnHelpHandler;
end;

procedure TMyForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnHelp := nil;
end;

function TMyForm.MyOnHelpHandler(Command: Word; Data: THelpEventData; var CallHelp: Boolean): Boolean;
begin
  Result := ...;
end;
```

Alternatively, you can drop a [`TApplicationEvents`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.AppEvnts.TApplicationEvents) component onto your Form at design-time, and then create an `OnHelp` event handler for it using the Object Inspector.

Comment: I did it through TApplicationEvent. Thanks at lot.